# Animate adding/removing UISearchBar to/from UITableView tableViewHeader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a subclass of UITableViewController. I have code that can add/remove a UISearchBar to/from the tableHeaderView of my tableView. Here's the code I have to perform these tasks:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = uiSearchBar; //Make the search bar appear
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; //Make the search bar disappear
```

The problem is that I want the adding/removing of the UISearchBar to be animated; slide into view from the top when I add it then slide upwards and out of view when I remove it instead of just appearing and disappearing. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out. Turned out to be pretty simple. Instead of adding the UISearchBar to the table header, I insert it into the first cell of the table with animation UITableViewRowAnimationTop and remove it using the same method. This results in the bar sliding in and out from the top. Here is the code that makes the bar appear:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.baseUiTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.baseUiTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

And here is the code that removes the search bar:

```
[uiSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.baseUiTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Comment: Will this approach have any impact on the row index selected when handling cell interactions?

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler way that is also suitable for UITableViewStyleGrouped (plus doesn't require changing the number of rows) is to animate the `contentInset` of the table:

```
CGFloat h = uiSearchBar.bounds.size.height;
UITableView *tv = self.tableView;
if (tv.tableHeaderView)
{  // hide bar
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
      tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-h, 0, 0, 0);
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      tv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
      tv.tableHeaderView = nil;
      [tv scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
   }];
}
else
{  // show bar
   uiSearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, -h, tv.frame.size.width, h);
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
      [tv scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
      tv.tableHeaderView = uiSearchBar;
   }];
}
```

I know this is three years after the OP asked the question, but since this is a good alternative to achieve the desired effect, I thought it might be useful for others meeting the same problem.

Comment: spot an error...Or am i wrong? `tv.size.width` has to be `tv.frame.size.width` and maybe `tv.size.height` needs a reduction to, for example 44.0f or just h.

Comment: Indeed! +1 for spotting this. Thanks. I've fixed this in the code above.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, however I'm trying to get my head around how the "show" part of this works.. why does it make the frame animate? Is it because when you add the bar to the tableview it sets the bar's frame origin y to 0 which causes it to animate down from -h?

Comment: Indeed. When you set `tv.tableHeaderView = uiSearchBar` it automatically sets `uiSearchBar.frame.origin.y = 0`, which is being animated like all frame properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your table view scroll—animated—so that only the row below the search bar is visible, then remove the search bar and scroll to the same row without animation.